# JSF Mapping with Maven - starting using maven

Tags: jsf, maven, mapping, pom.xml, web.xml

hope you had a great day
For a few days I am trying to learn using Maven - cause I have heard that its good practice to create my projects with it.
And so what I did. Maven is quite difficult for my present abilities. Now I am trying to create JSF page and 've got problem with mapping. Maven has created a simple web.xml for me, its almost empty (it has just  tag and its closed too). I have added JSF depenedency and made simple a.xhtml page with one button and text field. If I run it, it works fine. But If I enter some changes in web.xml - I would add mapping for *.jsf *.faces *.xhtml etc. it wont work anymore. I am sick about it, have no idea how to fix it.

Here is my present code:
pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.maciej</groupId>
  <artifactId>Mejwn</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Mejwn Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>Mejwn</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
              id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>a.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My project structure:
http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/13/qr18.jpg
(I cant add images, too low reputation for now:P)

Hope you can help me! 
Thanks! ;)

Comment: actually, in the picture there is no jsf-impl because I deleted it from dependencies cause it wouldnt helped

Comment: 'it wont work anymore' and what is the error? How are you running your project?

Comment: @max_yashin thanks god that you answered me:P My error is 404 - so as i know, client is able to find the server, but cannot find file. I tried lots kinds of URL's: with project name/without, with a.xhtml/jsf/faces Nothing helped. HOW I RUN: I have made tomcat "instance" in IntelliJ and I press "run server". Then I am doing right click on the page and "Show in browser" and it shows in my Google Chrome. Today morning, I was trying to fix it and the problem occurs when I add ANY enter about mapping. When i add only <servlet> with servlet name and class its working fine, but with mappings its not

Comment: You should find your server's console output: logs should be there, it could help you later

Comment: @max_yashin you mean my error that shows in IDE in console? there was no errors, just server starting info :) On the page, when i entered on it, was just ordinary 404 error, i guess so.. anyway thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I have fixed it. The problem was in pom.xml, I had to add those dependencies:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.4</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.4</version>
  </dependency>
```

And all mappings and rendering JSF components(which hasnt been working as well) are fine now
Thanks and have a good day